# How can I populate a std::vector from a buffer and its size?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have what I believe is a simple question about the [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) type. The underlying problem is straightforward: I have a function that reads a stream of data into a buffer (as well as getting the buffer's size), then returns a that data as a vector. The type for the collection elements is fixed, uint8_t. My question is, is there a better way for me to populate the vector than walking the buffer?

Here is my naive, harebrained code:

```
uint8_t* buffer;
size_t size;
stream->readBuffer(buffer, size); // I don't own the stream class
std::vector<uint8_t> output(size);
for (size_t i = 0; i < currentChunkLength; i++)
{
    output.push_back(buffer[i]);
}
return output;
```

Comment: `std::vector<uint8_t>(buffer, buffer+size);` PS: if you initialize a vector with a size, don't use push back you'll end up with twice the elements, of which the first half have default values.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that similar question (I didn't consider my pointer and length to be a c-style array). Surprisingly the answers are all different! Regardless it looks like I should close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could read in one step (you own the `vector`):

```
std::vector<uint8_t> output(size);
stream->readBuffer(output.data(), output.size());
```

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't considered this. Just because I'm curious, what are the pros and cons reading directly into the vector? I'm assuming that at a minimum I'm saving one memory allocation?

Comment: If the readBuffer method allocates the memory itself I don't think you can do this.

Comment: @fatcat1111 a memcpy in to what? in your example the buffer ptr is unitialized

Comment: `std::vector` is continuous and memory leak free. This is the C++ way of heap memory use of simple types. (I haven't called `delete` or `delete []` directly for years.)

Comment: @fatcat1111 my point exactly, in your example not pointing to anything so memcopying into it is bad.

Answer (score 18):

Use the constructor taking iterators:

```
std::vector<unit8_t> output(buffer, buffer + size);
```